# expressjs v5 release date?

Tags: node.js, express, http2

There was one small commit for express in June but then nothing since January (before it was acquired by StrongLoop and subsequently IBM). It seems like it has been collecting dust ever since StrongLoop acquired it... Does anyone have any idea when they might start getting a move on? Even discussion around the issue seems to be dead too. It would be great to finally see http2 support, I can't believe such a popular framework like express still doesn't have it, it's been lagging behind for a while now.

Comment: It still doesn’t have it. The contributors are active and working hard, but the development seems noticeably slow.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At the moment, there no finite date for Express 5 release. Express 4 is pretty stable, so we are in more of a maintenance mode while we await finalization of HTTP/2 in node core among other things.

There is a bunch of stuff [planned for Express 5](https://github.com/expressjs/express/pull/2237). Some of them have been completed, but we'd want something major like HTTP/2 or promise support before we ship Express 5.

You can actually [use HTTP/2 already with Express](https://github.com/indutny/node-spdy).

FYI, Express is now [a part of Node.js Foundation](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/foundation-express-news/). It does not belong to StrongLoop/IBM.

And, by the way, we have an active [Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/expressjs/express).

Comment: what is the diff between these 2 modules.
https://github.com/spdy-http2/node-spdy VS https://github.com/nodejs/http2